# How is the measurement of the $Z_0Z_2$ error syndrome realised by these two circuits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-error-correction

I am told that the following quantum circuit diagram implements the $Z_0Z_2$ error syndrome, but I don't follow.

[image]

I understand error syndromes when expressed in matrix form and how performing $Z_0Z_2|001\rangle=-|001\rangle$ for example can be used to identify single bit-flip errors. But I don't follow how this is achieved in this circuit? I might not understand the perpendicular connections properly. I read the perpendicular connection from $|a\rangle$ to $|q_2\rangle$ as a "Controlled-Z", meaning Z is only applied if $|a\rangle$ is $|1\rangle$. But with this interpretation the ancilliary bit is never updated, and $HH|0\rangle$ will always measure $0$?

There is a second implementation of the $Z_0Z_2$ error syndrome. This circuit is apparently equivalent to the first I have shared, but this one is much clearer in its function to me. So alternatively if you can show me how these two circuits are equivalent that will also resolve this issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points are important to this:

1. The controlled Z gate is symmetric: It is irrelevant which of the qubits you call the "control" and which the "target". So you can put the Z on the bottom line instead in the first figure.
2. $HZH=X$. Thus, if you Hadamard-transform the controlled Z (after flipping where you write the Z), you obtain controlled-X gates, i.e., CNOTs. (You just have to insert a resolution of the identity $HH=I$ between the two Z's/controls on the A line.)

Thus, the second circuit is completely equivalent to the first one (even if you omit the initial state of $|a\rangle$ and the measurment).